# how can i Navigate the Image(including Text on Image)?

Tags: flutter

I want to add images with text  in one page and navigate the whole page to the other page (issue is only image is navigate not text ) please help.

Like in Image editor application you want to add text and save this page and now you want add frames in that same Image.

My problem is when I add some text and save and move onto frames screen
only IMAGE is navigate not TEXT.(which I add in the Previous screen )

Comment: Please be more specific , include some relevant code examples as well

Comment: what I'm saying is pass the image with text into a next screen

Comment: how do you exactly add text ?

Comment: yes add text and navigate that image with text to next screen